# How do I hide an image within a gallery with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

[image][image]I have a gallery plugin on my Shopify website which doesn't have an option to hide an image within the gallery. It does have a custom CSS option within the gallery so I'm trying to find out if anyone knows how to hide a certain image in a gallery using the CSS option.

I want to hide an image within the gallery - not the entire gallery.

The HTML code for the gallery is:

```html
<div class="cz-embed-gallery" id="cz-embed-gallery3926"></div>
```

The images have a caption, image link, and a title.

Take a look and see if you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **CSS option**?

Comment: @Quentin It gives me an option to add custom CSS to the gallery.

Comment: Does your images within the gallery have unique ID, class, data value, or anything else?

Comment: Add your generated HTML structure or a link to your website, that will be easier to help you.

Comment: I've updated this post with an image of the the dashboard of the images. Also the link to my website is: https://real97entertainment.com/ the gallery is under the "Today's Videos" section

Answer (score 0):

You can hide any element by assigning `display: none` to the class, id or whatever is valid in CSS as an identifier.

Take a look a the basics of CSS.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: I want to hide an image within the gallery - not the entire gallery, is this how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Every image in your gallery must have a unique id or some sort of a unique identifier. The identifier of your image is your target. Can you post a link maybe?

Comment: I've updated this post with an image of the the dashboard of the images. Also the link to my website is: real97entertainment.com the gallery is under the "Today's Videos" section

Comment: Okay looks like they don't have a unique id by shopify itself. But there is still hope! You can work with other identifiers aswell or just take a look at the nth-child selector.

Comment: Do you think the title or caption can be used as the unique ID?

Comment: Oh wait... if I am seeing this right your website uses an iframe to display the gallery... Well this is making things much, much worse and I am kinda losing my hope now. You can't access an iframe via your own CSS...

Comment: So this wouldn't be possible?

Comment: Not in this way at least. You need to find another way to implement your gallery and definetly without an iframe. It is even making things much worse because this iframe is cross domain and there is NO way to change your CSS, short answer:
No.

Comment: The gallery gives me a "Custom CSS" box to add code for the gallery itself.

Comment: Oh if you can change the CSS for your gallery this is changing things. But let's stop extending the question in the comments. Stackoverflow is already warning me :) Let's start a chat and I will post the answer if we are finished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181819/discussion-between-aaron3219-and-adrian).